# Select first value of a group in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to select

```
Date         Store_ID  Item_ID   Start_Q    Sold     Transferred  End_Q
07-31-2015       1        X1         50       20           0         30
07-31-2015       1        X2         30       10           10        10 
08-01-2015       1        X1         30       10           0         20
08-02-2015       1        X1         20       0            10        10  
08-03-2015       1        X2         10       5             0         5
```

I want to select Item movement in store 1 from '20-7-2015' to '30-8-2015' 
to be like that

```
Item_ID    Start_Q    Sum_Sold    Sum_Transferred     End_Q
   X1        50          30             10              10  
   X2        30          15             10               5
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it. If you're in SQL Server 2012 or newer, you can do this without the inner selects by using window functions.

```
select
  Item_ID,
  (select top 1 Start_Q from Table1 T2 where T2.Item_ID = T1.ItemID order by date asc) as StartQ,
  Sum_Sold,
  Sum_Transferred,
  (select top 1 End_Q from Table1 T2 where T2.Item_ID = T1.Item_ID order by date desc) as End_Q
from
(
  select 
    Item_ID,
    sum(Sold) as Sum_Sold,
    sum(transferred) as Sum_Transferred
  from
    table1
  group by
    Item_ID
) T1
```

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/61a71/1)

Comment: thanks for answering ,and how to select that in this time period

Comment: also I want To select in Specific Store

Comment: @Atemu Then just add storeId into the selects + group by

Comment: I have added the store and worked correctly thank you .if it's not too much . i need to select movement between two dates i try it but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Item_ID,
    MAX(Start_Q),
    Sum(Sold),   
    Sum(Transferred),
    MIN(End_Q)
FROM your_table
WHERE  [Date] BETWEEN '20-07-2015' AND '30-08-2015'
GROUP BY Item_ID
ORDER BY Item_ID
```

Comment: i want to select the first Start_Q  and the last End_Q in this period for each Item not the min or max

Comment: @Atemu, then please use the JamesZ's answer.  However, base on your simple data, MAX start_Q and MIN End_Q should be same as the first Start Q and last END_q, unless you have other types transactions not listed on here.

Comment: yes i have Entered_Q that is added to Start_Q for the next Date

Answer (score 0):

Using `CROSS APPLY`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e46779/1/0)

```
SELECT
    Item_ID,
    Start_Q = s.Start_Q,
    Sum_Sold = SUM(Sold),
    Sum_Transferred = SUM(Transferred),
    End_Q = e.End_Q
FROM tbl t
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 Start_Q
    FROM tbl
    WHERE
        Item_ID = t.Item_ID
        AND [Date] BETWEEN '20150720' AND '20150830'
    ORDER BY [Date] ASC
)s
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 End_Q
    FROM tbl
    WHERE
        Item_ID = t.Item_ID
        AND [Date] BETWEEN '20150720' AND '20150830'
    ORDER BY [Date] DESC
)e
WHERE
    t.Date BETWEEN '20150720' AND '20150830'
GROUP BY t.Item_ID, s.Start_Q, e.End_Q
```